# How can i display grouped values in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm Trying to display restaurant Menus grouped by the categories, for example...

- Lunch

  - Chicken and Chips
  - Rice
- Breakfast

  - Tea
  - Coffee

So I have 3 tables in my database, Restaurants, Categories, And Menus

**Category** Model

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
    */
    public function menus_type()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Menu','category_id');
    }
}
```

**Menu** Model

```
class Menu extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'price',
        'description',
        'photoPath',
        'restaurant_id',
        'category_id',
    ];

    /**
     * Menu belongs to Restaurant
     */
    public function restaurant()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Restaurant');
    }

    /**
     * Menu belongs to category type 
     */
    public function category_type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
    }

}
```

**Restaurants controller**

```
public function show($slug, RestaurantRepository $repository){
      if(! $restaurant = $repository->get(['slug' => $slug], with(['cuisines','user', 'photos', 'thumbs', 'region', 'ratings.user']))) return abort('404');

      $menus=Menu::with(['category_type'])->where('restaurant_id',$restaurant->id)->get()->groupBy('category_id');

       return view('frontend.restaurant.show', compact('restaurant', 'p','menus'));
}
```

when i **Dump** this it looks just fine.

[image: This is what is returned from the $menu variable]

Results have been grouped

[image: Expand results set with relationships]

Now my trouble is on the **View** when i try to get results of this i get an error.

```
   @if($menus)
   <ul>
     @foreach($menus as $m)
       <li>
         {{$m->name}}
       </li>
     @endforeach
   </ul>
   @endif
```

> > > ErrorException (E_ERROR).
> > >
> > > Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: When you loop over `$menus`, isn't `$m` itself an array of collection?

Comment: Also, there is no `name` in the `Menu` property as it stands.

Comment: add `->toArray()` after `groupBy('category_id')` https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-toarray

Comment: Looking at your objective, groupBy() seems redundant when you can make use of dynamic property of relationships when looping itself in your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate inner loop also. 'groupBy()' creates another array with `category_id` as key.

```
@if($menus)
 <ul>
 @foreach($menus as $category_id=>$outer)
  @foreach($outer as $k=>$inner)
   <li>
      {{$category_id}}: {{$inner->name}}
   </li>
   @endforeach
 @endforeach
 </ul>
 @endif
```

Updated you query to get from category

```
$categories = Category::with('menus_type')->get();
return view('frontend.restaurant.show', compact('restaurant', 'p','categories '));
```

In your view

```
@if($categories ?? false)
 <ul>
 @foreach($categories ?? [] as $cat_key=>$category)
  <li>
      {{$category->name}}
  </li>
  <li>
  <ul>
  @foreach($category->menus_type as $menu_key=>$menu)
  <li>
      {{$menu->name}}
  </li> 
  @endforeach
  </ul>
  </li>
 @endforeach
 </ul>
 @endif
```

Comment: That seems to work Thanks a lot, Now the list need to be nested under one category as shown above. so the first <li> Will be Lunch, then its menu items

Comment: `<ul>
                    @foreach($menus as $category_id=>$outer)
                     @foreach($outer as $k=>$inner)
                      <li>
                         {{$category_id}}
                         <ul>
                             <li>{{$inner->name}}</li>
                        
                        </ul> 
                      </li>
                      @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                    </ul>
                    @endif`

Comment: @Wells: do you have Category model if yes share that in your question ?

Comment: @wels : Please try to list your `Category` with one to many relation with `Menu`.

Comment: that's great thanks now I'm getting menu items that do not belong to the restaurant , restaurant_id, should i change the relationship here?

Comment: `where('restaurant_id',$restaurant->id)`

Comment: each restaurant has it's own categories and menu items